# Simplify $grad(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{x})$

Tags: vector-analysis

> Simplify $grad(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{x})$, where $\vec{a}$ is a constant vector.

My attempt: 
\begin{align}
grad(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{x})&=grad(a_1x+a_2y+a_3z)\\
& = \frac{\partial (a_1x+a_2y+a_3z)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial (a_1x+a_2y+a_3z)}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial (a_1x+a_2y+a_3z)}{\partial z}\\
& = a_1+a_2+a_3
\end{align}

But this does not equal the answer $\vec{a}$.

Comment: The gradient is a vector not a scalar. Do you see your mistake?

Comment: Yep, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the directions in each term

$$
\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\color{blue}{\hat{x}} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\color{blue}{\hat{y}} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\color{blue}{\hat{z}}
$$

So in your case

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla ({\bf a}\cdot {\bf x}) &=&  \frac{\partial ({\bf a}\cdot {\bf x}) }{\partial x}\color{blue}{\hat{x}} + \frac{\partial ({\bf a}\cdot {\bf x}) }{\partial y}\color{blue}{\hat{y}} + \frac{\partial ({\bf a}\cdot {\bf x}) }{\partial z}\color{blue}{\hat{z}} \\
&=& a_1  \color{blue}{\hat{x}} + a_2 \color{blue}{\hat{y}} + a_3 \color{blue}{\hat{z}} = {\bf a}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Ah that was silly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It should have been

$$\begin{align}
grad(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{x})&=grad(a_1x+a_2y+a_3z)\\
& = (\frac{\partial (a_1x+a_2y+a_3z)}{\partial x},\frac{\partial (a_1x+a_2y+a_3z)}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial (a_1x+a_2y+a_3z)}{\partial z})\\
 = (a_1,a_2,a_3)
\end{align}$$